# Bottom margin not taken into account, div are overlapping, why?

Tags: css, html, overlap

I am implementing a typical header, left col, mid col, right col, footer layout. I have wrapped the lft,mid,right `div`s in a midBlock `div`. I am including a picture to make it clear:

[image]

I have set a bottom margin of 10px on the midBlock, however, it overlaps with the footer. Why? And how to solve it?

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KJsQa/1/).

Here is my CSS:

```
body {
    background-image:url('./img/GreenLetters.jpg');
}

#blankPage {
    background-color: #fffffd;
    width: 1020px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    border: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    position:relative;
}

#header {
    background-color: #000000;
    color:red;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
    border: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
}

#midBlock {
    margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
    border: 0px;
    width: 1020px;
    position:relative;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
}

#leftCol {
    background-color: #123456;
    width: 160px;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
}

#midCol {
    background-color: #654321;
    width: 660px;
    margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
    border: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    position:absolute;
    left:170px;
    top:0px;
}

#rightCol {
    background-color: #567890;
    width: 160px;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    position:absolute;
    left:860px;
    top:0px;
}


#footer {
    background-color: #000000;
    color:red;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
    border: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    position:relative;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution by setting:

```
min-height:1px;
overflow:auto;
```

in the midBlock css. Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KJsQa/2/).

It creates another issue, but a solution has been found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292249/making-englobing-parent-div-as-high-as-inner-divs/14292371#14292371).