# Making englobing/parent div as high as inner divs

Tags: css, html

As part of creating a typical left, mid, right column layout, I need to wrap some inner `div`s of various height into an englobing/parent div. I need to make sure the global/parent `div` is as high as the highest inner `div`, which depends of the text it contains. The `min-height` property won't cut it.

How should I proceed? Should I use tables and cells instead of `div`s?

I am including a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cj75q/) to describe the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to achieve something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Cj75q/3/

If I'm right you don't need all these `relative` and `absolute` positions, all you need is float left of the columns:

```
#leftCol {
    background-color: #123456;
    width: 23%;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    float: left;
}

#midCol {
    background-color: #654321;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
    border: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left
}

#rightCol {
    background-color: #567890;
    width: 23%;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please write your code here and then I think I can help you to find your solution.

In normal situation, the global `div` usually has the height of highest inner `div`. But I don't know what is your problem exactly.

Comment: If you click on the JSFiddle link I have put in the question, you will access the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code can solve your problem. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cj75q/17/)

But I suggest you to use table in this type of situations. Because the `float` and `width` properties on `div` tag can cause serious problems in some browsers.